# Specify a breakpoint for all a function call in IDA Pro 6.1

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, ida

In IDA Pro 6.1, I have a dll which has twenty calls to the "CreateFileA" and "CreateFileW" function APIs.

I would like to specify breakpoints for all the CreateFileA/CreateFileW automatically.

I could do it manually for all the xrefs, but that is tedious.
Is there a way to specify a breakpoint directly for the CreateFileA/CreateFileW call?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You could set a break point at the first instruction of both CreateFile, or you could whip something up with IDAPython to create the breakpoints.

Iterate over all the instructions/calls and look for calls to the appropriate function.

add_bpt() I believe is the call,

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script I wrote up to accomplish what you want. It sets soft-breakpoints at the locations that call your specified functions.

```
// Script used to set a breakpoint at the callsite
// of the specified function using cross-references.
#include <idc.idc>

static SetBreakpoint(location)
{
  // Sets a breakpoint to be activated when
  // the debugger runs over the address.
  AddBptEx(location, 0, BPT_SOFT);
}

static CrossReferenceSource(source)
{
  // Find the linear address of the source
  // location to start xref'ing from.
  auto sourcefn = LocByName(source);
  auto iterfn = DfirstB(sourcefn);

  if (sourcefn != BADADDR && iterfn != BADADDR)
  {

    do
    {
      Message("Setting breakpoint @ 0x%08x\n", iterfn);
      SetBreakpoint(iterfn);
      iterfn = DnextB(sourcefn, iterfn);
    } while(iterfn != BADADDR);
}
}

static main()
{
  auto source = "FunctionName";

  Message("--- Setting breakpoints at cross-reference ---\n");
  CrossReferenceSource(source);
  Message("--- Finished settings breakpoints --\n");
}
```

Replace "FunctionName" with the name of your function and run it within IDA's 'Execute Script' window available through `File > Script command`

A known limitation is that it won't recognize indirect cross-references (e.g. calls using the registers).

Answer (score 0):

If CreateFileA/W are all imports (ie, externs defined in an .idata section), can you not just select the symbol in question and hit F2 (add breakpoint)? The Breakpoint settings dialog that comes up allows you to specify the Hardware breakpoint mode, which in this case we would want to limit to Read (since the symbol's value would be written to at startup when imports are resolved), which should only happen in 'call ds:CreateFileA' instances.

Some breakpoint notes from the IDA Help:

- It is impossible to create more than 4 hardware breakpoints
- Please note that hardware breakpoints occur AFTER the instruction execution while software breakpoints occur BEFORE the instruction.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know and according with kornman00 "CreateFile" is imported from a dll. In fact, it is imported directly from Kernel32.dll, You can take a look here if you are not sure how it works.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Therefore, In order to do what you are looking for, the best approach is going directly to it, set the breakpoint in kernel32.CreateFileA or kernel32.CreateFileW. The differences are just if the app use Ansichar or Widechar.

Obviously in order to do that, you need to start the debug process because kernel32 must be load for your app before you will be able to set a break-point there.

If you are getting confuse my advice is "load the binary in a simpler debugger" and try to figure out what we explained you before